# SharePoint capabilities in Office 365 GCC High

Tags: office-365, site-template, content-editor-web-part, aspx, migration

My company recently migrated from MS Office 365 *Commercial tenant* to their *Government Community Cloud [(GCC) High](https://www.agileit.com/news/microsoft-365-government-cloud-computing/) tenant* to comply with Dept of Defense [CMMC](https://www.acq.osd.mil/cmmc/) requirements.

Post migration of our SP hub, my site collection lost the following:

- Ability to enable custom code: CEWP and custom InfoPath forms are not available.
- All custom .aspx pages display as blank, but the HTML code remained intact and still makes reference to the non-showing webparts.
- Cannot save sites or lists/libraries as Templates. Related to this, we also lost the Web Designer Galleries in Site Collection Settings.
- Lists/libraries templates show up in "Site Settings > Site Administration > Site libraries and lists" menu, but do not show up in the "Add an app" list of available templates.

We tried [enabling custom code at the tenant level](https://sharepointmaven.com/2-reasons-why-you-cannot-save-site-as-template-in-sharepoint/) and waited 24 hours for the change to take without success. We also checked that "Publishing Infrastructure" had not been accidentally Activated in Site Collection Settings. The Microsoft Support rep believes that those 2 features are not available in GCC High (he promised to send us documentation) and said there are many cases open because people want the features but they don't know when it will be available.

I would wait if I didn't have a couple of urgent projects that would leverage those capabilities. **Does anyone have experience in Office GCC High and know of a solution/workaround to these issues?**

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research and testing (and offline assistance from Greg Zelfond [SP Maven]), my IT dept and I figured out that the inability to customize anything was due to some loss/corruption of our access rights during the migration to GCC on this specific Site Collection. Even after trying to reset our access (both IT and myself as a SC admin), nothing worked -- so we decided to create a new SC, and it's all back to normal, albeit the pain in the rear that it is to recreate my previous sites in this new SC. Unfortunately, I don't have any lessons-learned to share from the migration standpoint, I was not part of those discussions with the migration consultant. The good news is that GCC does not impact SP customization after all :)